# How do I post the details of a question without having my question closed out on this platform?

Tags: support, comments, closed-questions

I posted a question in very simple terms earlier today: [Can ANYONE help me with getting my phone that is stuck in a boot loop to be "seen" by any of my computers to get the files out? Details in the body](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246618). I took a VERY long time typing out all the details and specifics in the body, but the body only allows a very limited number of letters before it is "full." Since it didn't take my entry due to the length, I opted to start in the body then add the rest in the comments. The comments section allows for even less characters to be inputted. So I had to use A LOT of comment entries to adequately and fully describe the issue. But then my question was flagged and closed by a moderator because the details were not in the question or body, and I am not supposed to use the comments section to further describe the question, but was told to provide great detail.

How am I supposed to do that? I need quite a bit of space to describe the problem adequately, but the platform doesn't provide a lot of space. But I am not allowed to use the comments section to continue describing. Where's the give? Can anyone tell me how I can find the help I need by asking the question in a way the system asks me to but seems to not allow me to? Thank you!

Comment: The answer is simple: Do not use comments, use your question. Stackexchange is not a forum.

Comment: "*but the body only allows a very limited number of letters before it is "full."*" sorry, could you mention the character limits you're facing? AFAIK, the usual character limit on a post is 30000 characters, so I'm quite confused by this statement considering that all of your comments took roughly 15000 chars (which is considered long enough compared to the average questions, but still half of the usual limit).

Comment: short your question to single problem. short your wot to essential points. *"Samsung Note 20 Plus Ultra got stuck in a boot loop after the last update"* is all we need to know